# Define an array of user defined type on heap

Tags: c++, arrays, object, heap-memory

How DO I define a user defined object array on heap for eg

If I have a class Node object and I want to define an array of Node* on heap like

```
arr = new Node*[1000];
```

How is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want 1000 Node object, then

```
Node *arr = new Node[1000];
```

if you want 1000 Node*, then

```
Node **arr = new Node*[1000];
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this,

```
Node** arr = new Node*[1000];
```

Because looking at `new Node*[1000];` looks like you are initializing pointer to pointer.